# Migrating GNU Screen questions to Unix/Linux Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, migration, site-recommendation

I found a question about GNU Screen on Stack Overflow and almost flagged it for migration to Unix/Linux Stack Exchange, but then I noted that there are many of these questions on Stack Overflow: some were migrated to Super User, others were not.

What do you think? Should these questions be migrated to Unix Stack Exchange? It seems to be a better place to ask this kind of question, and it would be nice for Unix Stack Exchange to get some more content, but maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: The thing is: They're *equally* valid for [unix.SE] *and* [SU].

Comment: I have mixed feelings about the 'off topicness' , as screen is something many programmers use. But, it's not _really_ a tool specific to programming. Then again, you could write a book with emacs.

Comment: @slhck it seems that the Unix.SX site is the object of some controversies, but I am not going into this thing, actually. My doubt is mostly about whether GNU screen questions can/should be migrated. They could be migrated to SU too, anyway; my point is mostly about the migration of the content.

Comment: @TimPost I have just the same mixed feelings of yours - this is why I posted this question :)

Comment: I added some suggestions in the tag wiki of [tag:gnu-screen] about alternative sites. You all may be interested on looking at it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Most [gnu-screen](/questions/tagged/gnu-screen) questions are computer user questions, not computer programming questions, so they are off-topic on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/) and on-topic on [Super User](https://superuser.com/) and [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) (or occasionally [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/) if the question is absolutely tied to Ubuntu, or [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) if the question is specific to Mac OS X, or [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com/) if screen is being used specifically to aid in the management of multiple computers).

Since only Super User is a migration target from Stack Overflow, migrate these questions to Super User unless you have a compelling reason to choose another site. (Server Fault is also a migration target, but most [gnu-screen](/questions/tagged/gnu-screen) questions are not SF material.)

Remember the golden rule of migrations: *migration is “we want it”, not “let them have it”*. If you wouldn't be comfortable having the question on “your” site, don't vote or flag for migration. If you're not sure whether the question is on-topic on the potential target site, don't vote for migration (if there's no migration path and you think that the question is *good* but misplaced, it's ok to flag; moderators will ask moderators of the target site if they're in doubt).

It's ok to vote to close and migrate to Super User as long as you're reasonably confident that the question is on-topic there (if the question is about Screen, it probably is) and you follow the first corollary of the golden rule: *don't migrate crud*.

Comment: Server Fault is a migration target as well.

Comment: _If you're not a regular of the target site, don't vote or flag for migration._ I am not a regular user of Super User but I feel I am smart enough to know what would be a good question there :) Could I vote for migration? Also, could I _massively_ purpose [tag:gnu-screen] questions to be migrated to SU? Would it be polite/reasonable/acceptable?

Comment: @brandizzi I stated that a bit too strongly, but only vote to migrate if you're really confident that the question is good and on-topic on the target site. If you're not sure, close as off-topic. Migrating old questions that have been satisfactorily answered is not very useful; it would be best to check whether they already have a duplicate on the target site, and simply close as off-topic on SO if they do.